# How to use entity manager in SoapService

Tags: symfony, soap, doctrine

I am trying to do a service which returns some records from DB. The problem is that I can't get to the EntityManager in my controller.
Service return an empty result. When I change it to return random string it works fine. But in this way it is not working as it should be.

```
use BeSimple\SoapBundle\ServiceDefinition\Annotation as Soap;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class DefaultController extends ContainerAware
{
    /**
     * @Soap\Method("getPolicy")
     * @Soap\Result(phpType = "GL\WebServiceBundle\Entity\Policy[]")
     */
    public function getPolicy()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

        $policies = $em->getRepository('GLPolicyBundle:Policy')->findBySentDate(null);

        return var_dump($policies);
        return $policies; 
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying the $em is null?  You have DefaultController defined as a service?  You not just pointing your route directly to DefaultController??

Comment: I have investigated this more carefully end I found $em is ok, the problem is that the return value of the service is wrong. When i return for example array of string everything is working, problem start when I try to return GL\WebServiceBundle\Entity\Policy[] or GL\WebServiceBundle\Entity\Policy then it is not working.

Comment: Does $policyRepository->findAll() work?

Comment: Yes it works, the problem is when i try to return complex type as my entity. I leave this bundle and start to use php soap, thanks for help.